# Is a fixed partition key bad practice?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with:

- Timestamp (HASH)
- Text (String)

I want to be able to get the latest item via a query, but doing so requires that I *sort* by `Timestamp` rather than partition by it. I was considering doing this instead:

- Partition (HASH, hard-coded as whatever)
- Timestamp (RANGE)
- Text (String)

That way I can query and pass a hard-coded partition in.

But is this bad practice?

Comment: You should include all use cases for context. I answered your question as it, assuming this is the only use case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The main thing to consider is that partitions have a finite throughput for both reads and writes. This is independent from the provisioned throughput for the table. Partition throughput is constrained by the hard disk's read and write speeds. Remember that all items with the same hash value will live on the same partition and therefore will be written to the same disk (discounting replication).

So, it depends on your scale. It will work for a small scale, low throughput use case but it won't be able to scale beyond a single disk.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually bad practice to use a single, hard coded value for your hash key. Rather than a hard coded hash key value, you should consider using year_month_day (or some variation) as your hash key for this use case. It's still not great, but it's much better than a single value.

If you do want to use hard coded hash key values, consider using multiple hard coded values to [shard your data across partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html).